# How can i use react query and codegen generated functions in getServerSideProps in Next js?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, apollo-client, react-query, codegen

I have already used Apolloclient with Codegen in Next js.
To fetch data in server side, I used this code.

```
      const { data }: { data: FilterDataQuery } =
        await client(req).query({
          query: FilterDataDocument,
          variables: { orderBy: ASC },
        });
```

Now I want to use React query with next js.
how can i use react query functions and hooks that was generated with codegen in getServerSideProps

Comment: have you read the docs on this topic? Do you have a more specific question? https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr

Comment: thank you @TkDodo, I read the docs and it was solved.